# How to get image outline (Or getting specific colour from image?) -android

Tags: android, image

See below image and it contains some black outline and i want get only those outline. means all other part of image should be invisible.

how can i achieve this?

I'm thinking is it possible to identify a  colour and invisible other colours?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make all other colors transparent using [PorterDuffXfermode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuffXfermode.html)

It looks as if in your case this may not be enough, as you have black regions in the photo. One option is to change the color of the black regions to a very dark gray  before adding the lines.

Comment: @ yoah thanks i will try that for outline i can set any unique color that is not a problem